# Create a nested array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Any suggestions on how to get nested arrays / objects from the following array of objects?

```
[
{COLOR: "Black", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Leather", SIZE: "S"}
{COLOR: "Black", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Leather", SIZE: "L"}
{COLOR: "Black", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Velvet", SIZE: "S"}
{COLOR: "Black", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Velvet", SIZE: "M"}
{COLOR: "Red", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Velvet", SIZE: "S"}
]
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
[
      {
        label: "Black",
        children: [
          { label: "Leather", children: [{ label: "S" }, { label: "L" }] },

          { label: "Velvet", children: [{ label: "S" }, { label: "M" }] }
        ]
      },

      {
        label: "Red",
        children: [{ label: "Velvet", children: [{ label: "S" }] }]
      }
];
```

I managed to do it for objects with 2 properties but not more than that, and I cant figure out how to do it for objects with N properties.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Build a function that can group an array of objects (with no "sub"-arrays) for a given key: `function groupBy(array, key) { /* ... */ return groupedArray; }`. If this works then just use this same function for the `children`s of the grouped `label`s

Comment: @Olian04 I generated one object for each COLOR and and added the FABRIC_DESIGN children accordingly just by watching to which COLOR it belongs. But when I get to the SIZE I cant continue because a SIZE belongs to a combination of COLOR and FABRIC_DESIGN, worse still if there are more properties. Sorry if I am not clear, I am quite new

Comment: @brako thats fine, but please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using `reduce` and `forEach` methods and one object to keep the data of each level.

```js
const data = [{COLOR: "Black", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Leather", SIZE: "S"},{COLOR: "Black", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Leather", SIZE: "L"},{COLOR: "Black", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Velvet", SIZE: "S"},{COLOR: "Black", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Velvet", SIZE: "M"},{COLOR: "Red", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Velvet", SIZE: "S"}]

const result = []
const levels = {result}
const keys = ['COLOR', 'FABRIC_DESIGN', 'SIZE']

data.forEach(o => {
  keys.reduce((r, k, i, a) => {
    const label = o[k];

    if (!r[label]) {
      const value = {label}

      if (a[i + 1]) {
        r[label] = {result: []}
        value.children = r[label].result
      }

      r.result.push(value)
    }

    return r[label]
  }, levels)
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @brako Why did you accept a non-recursive answer when you explicitly ask for a recursive solution?

Comment: @brako Feel free to accept the answer that works best for you and helps you to solve your problem. If you think you don't need recursion you can always edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : 
Now, you can specify the hierarchy.

```js
var data = [
  {COLOR: "Black", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Leather", SIZE: "S"},
  {COLOR: "Black", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Leather", SIZE: "L"},
  {COLOR: "Black", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Velvet", SIZE: "S"},
  {COLOR: "Black", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Velvet", SIZE: "M"},
  {COLOR: "Red", FABRIC_DESIGN: "Velvet", SIZE: "S"}
]
var hierarchy = ['COLOR', 'FABRIC_DESIGN', 'SIZE'];

// temporary object to make uniqu entries
var structuredDatas = {};

data.forEach(el => {
  var editedDatas = structuredDatas;
  for (depth of hierarchy) {
    if (typeof el[depth] === 'undefined') {
      break;
    }
    if (!editedDatas[el[depth]]) {
      editedDatas[el[depth]] = { label: el[depth], children: {} };
    }
    editedDatas = editedDatas[el[depth]].children;
  }
});
// all data are structured

// next, we format data as expected
var formattedDatas = Object.values(structuredDatas).map(formatLevel)

function formatLevel(datas) {
  datas.children = Object.values(datas.children).map(formatLevel)
  return datas
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(formattedDatas, null, 2));
```

Comment: it works for this specific example, but if the size of the objects is not 3 or the property name change it doesnt. What I am trying to achieve is for arrays with objects that have a variable number of properties and unknown property names.

Comment: I understand, but Json ‘s key order can’t be used, because keys are not ordered. You must specify somewhere the hierarchy.

Comment: I created the objects out of arrays like: `  [
    { id: "COLOR", name: "Color", value_name: "Black" },
    { id: "FABRIC_DESIGN", name: "Fabric", value_name: "Leather" },
    { id: "SIZE", name: "Size", value_name: "S" }
  ]`  Do you think I´d better work with the arrays insted of creating the objects?